# docker: invalid reference format | error | cloud vm ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04

I created a vm (ubuntu-18.04 ) on Azure cloud and installed docker having a  version 17.09.0-ce. if I execute the docker commands like docker images, docker version from the bash it works.

However, when I try to execute the same commands from shell script like below, it throws errors.
Below is a script and an output. I also tried to run nginx:alpine but results were same.

> test.sh script

```
#!/bin/bash
#
echo "=== docker version==="
docker images
echo "==== Starut running a jmeter/image ===="
docker run "justb4/jmeter:latest"
echo "==== Finish ===="
```

> output

```
2020-05-24T21:39:58.1073920Z ========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
2020-05-24T21:39:58.1075676Z [command]/bin/bash --noprofile --norc /home/vsts/work/_temp/59e915fd-ea8a-4e36-8abb-8574d7a5bbf9.sh
2020-05-24T21:39:58.1141394Z === docker version===
2020-05-24T21:39:58.1221659Z docker: 'images
2020-05-24T21:39:58.1222312Z ' is not a docker command.
2020-05-24T21:39:58.1223386Z See 'docker --help'
2020-05-24T21:39:58.1224742Z ==== Starut running a jmeter/image ====
2020-05-24T21:39:58.1300191Z docker: invalid reference format.
2020-05-24T21:39:58.1300949Z See 'docker run --help'.
2020-05-24T21:39:58.1308872Z ==== Finish ====
2020-05-24T21:39:58.1326008Z 
2020-05-24T21:39:58.1391207Z ##[section]Finishing: Bash Script
```

Comment: Also docker run "justb4/jmeter:latest" from the bash download the image successfully.

Comment: Is it possible that your newlines are windows-style rather than linux-style? (if so, run `dos2unix` on the script)

Comment: @root: you are awesome, this worked. Yes conversion was a problem, when a file was created on windows, each line was being terminated with a Carriage Return followed by a Line Feed character. Script was showing the file as  #!/bin/bash^M having the special character at the end. when I tried after conversion using http://dos2unix.sourceforge.net/ , it worked.

Answer (score 1):

With Windows or DOS-style line endings , each line is terminated with a Carriage Return followed by a Line Feed character. If a script file was saved with Windows line endings, Bash sees the file as

#!/bin/bash^M
 ^M
 cd "src"^M

Try running dos2unix on the script solved the problem.

http://dos2unix.sourceforge.net/